# Prevent a Trigger From another trigger unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision-detection

How do i prevent a trigger from triggering when another trigger is activated. When a touch trigger is activated another triggered is activated without (anything noticeable in the code ) forcing that.

[Trigger 1 (The first one to be activated)]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger1 : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("Block2"));
    }
}
```

[Trigger 2 (the one to be activated after trigger one for no reason)]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Level2Win : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level3");
    }
}
```

Green Block = first trigger
Red Block = second trigger

[What the level looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osz1E.png)

Comment: I think your question isn't worded correctly? You want to load a new level when Trigger 2 is triggered, but Trigger 2 can only be Triggered AFTER Trigger 1 has been triggered? So, Trigger 1 -> Trigger 2 -> Load Scene "level3"?

Comment: Yes Trigger 1 causes Trigger 2 to be avaliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is to use an additional bool variable and an if statement in the trigger body. You could even use the built in 'enabled' property, remembering that triggers will fire regardless.

```
public class Trigger1 : MonoBehaviour {
 public Trigger2 trigger2;
 void Start()
  {
    trigger2.enabled=false;
  }
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
     trigger2.enabled=true;
  }
```

}

```
public class Trigger2 : MonoBehaviour {
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
 if (enabled)
    {do something else}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After clarifying that you're trying to enable a second Trigger after a first Trigger has been Triggered the following is the least intrusive way to add the feature (based on the code you've supplied):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Drag your Leve2Win trigger into the following Inspector object slot.
    public Level2Win Trigger2;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Trigger2.enabled = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("Block2"));
        Trigger2.enabled = true;
    }
}
```